# What is the proper way to dynamically change the color of a vertex in Metal?

Tags: ios, swift, metal

I am trying to get into Metal. I've done a bit of OpenGL, but it's been years so I can't think of the proper method to do this. I've been using the intro to Metal tutorials on Ray Wenderlich (http://www.raywenderlich.com/81399/ios-8-metal-tutorial-swift-moving-to-3d)

I have a Vertex struct:

```
struct Vertex
{
    var x, y, z: Float
    var r, g, b, a: Float

    func floatBuffer() -> Array<Float>
    {
        return [x, y, z, r, g, b, a]
    }
}
```

and a vertex buffer class:

```
class VertexBuffer
{
    var vertexData = Array<Float>()

    init(vertices: Array<Vertex>)
    {
        var vertexData = Array<Float>()

        for vertex in vertices
        {
            vertexData += vertex.floatBuffer()
        }

        self.vertexData = vertexData
    }

    func updateColorOfVertexAtIndex(index: Int, newRed: CGFloat, newGreen: CGFloat, newBlue: CGFloat, newAlpha: CGFloat)
    {
        let vertexDataIndex = index * 7

        if (vertexDataIndex < self.vertexData.count)
        {
            self.vertexData[vertexDataIndex + 3] = Float(newRed)
            self.vertexData[vertexDataIndex + 4] = Float(newGreen)
            self.vertexData[vertexDataIndex + 5] = Float(newBlue)
            self.vertexData[vertexDataIndex + 6] = Float(newAlpha)
        }
    }

    func updateColorOfVertexAtIndex(index: Int, newColor: UIColor)
    {
        var red: CGFloat = 0.0
        var green: CGFloat = 0.0
        var blue: CGFloat = 0.0
        var alpha: CGFloat = 0.0

        newColor.getRed(&red, green: &green, blue: &blue, alpha: &alpha)

        self.updateColorOfVertexAtIndex(index, newRed: red, newGreen: green, newBlue: blue, newAlpha: alpha)
    }
}
```

Based on the state of some other application stuff, I want to update the RGBA of one or more vertices. Using the `VertexBuffer.updateColor...` methods, I am updating the corresponding RGBA values in `VertexBuffer.vertexData`. I have a CADisplayLink hooked up to the functions below:

```
func diffusionLoop()
{
    self.updateVertexData()

    var vertexData = self.inkVertexBuffer.vertexData

    let dataSize = vertexData.count * sizeofValue(vertexData[0])
    let vertexBuffer = self.device.newBufferWithBytes(vertexData, length: dataSize, options: nil)


    autoreleasepool { () -> () in
        self.renderColorsWithVertexBuffer(vertexBuffer)
    }
}

func renderColorsWithVertexBuffer(vertexBuffer: MTLBuffer)
    {
        let renderPassDescriptor = MTLRenderPassDescriptor()
        let drawable = self.metalLayer.nextDrawable()

        renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].texture = drawable.texture
        renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].loadAction = .Clear
        renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].clearColor = MTLClearColorMake(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0)
        renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].storeAction = .Store

        let commandBuffer = self.commandQueue.commandBuffer()

        if let renderEncoder = commandBuffer.renderCommandEncoderWithDescriptor(renderPassDescriptor) {
            renderEncoder.setRenderPipelineState(self.pipelineState)
            renderEncoder.setVertexBuffer(vertexBuffer, offset: 0, atIndex: 0)
            renderEncoder.drawPrimitives(.Triangle, vertexStart: 0, vertexCount: self.vertexCount, instanceCount: self.triangleCount)
            renderEncoder.endEncoding()
        }

        commandBuffer.presentDrawable(drawable)
        commandBuffer.commit()
    }
```

The problem is, I have no idea if this is the correct way to do this. My aim is to frequently update the color of certain vertices, but is the answer to modify the vertex data and create a MTLBuffer out of it each time? Or something else?

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally you wouldn't want to update ***vertexBuffer***'s values. In my opinion the best way to do, what you are trying to do, is to keep immutable data separate from mutable data.

So I would create separate uniform buffer with color values and update it instead of ***vertexBuffer*** itself.

Also you said "***Based on the state of some other application stuff I want to update the RGBA of one or more vertices ...***", it might be better to pass those "**states**" as constants to the shader and inside of shader to calculate the color for each vertex or fragment.

Vertex shader has:

```
unsigned int vid [[ vertex_id ]]
```

with which you can explicitly set color for each vertex.

Comment: Hey this answer was helpful for me too. Can you provide some clarification for me?

I read in the docs that MTLBuffers are meant to be reused and you should avoid creating new ones when you can. But if you want to update the colors each frame it seems to me like you'd have to. So is the idea just that you only recreate as much storage as you need to by keeping the colors separate from the vertices?

Comment: @lancejabr You are absolutely right, allocating buffers on each draw call is a bad practice. 
What you need to do is to allocate a pool of buffers and reuse them, just like with UITableView cells.

There is an explanation about this in my tutorial https://www.raywenderlich.com/93997/ios-8-metal-tutorial-swift-part-3-adding-texture section "Reusing Uniform Buffers (optional)".

I think you should not include mutable color data in vertex data, but should pass it via uniform buffer, and read color from it in shader.