# What are the ways to change the color of an rendering object?

Tags: render, metal

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29553923/what-is-the-proper-way-to-dynamically-change-the-color-of-a-vertex-in-metal). I just started learning *Metal* and I am having difficulty translating *OpenGL* to *Metal*.
My case: I am creating multiple objects with different positioning. When tapping on any of the objects, it should change its color to monochrome. 
The layout for my vertex buffer looks like this:

> XYZRGBIJKXYZRGBIJKXYZRGBIJK.....XYZRGBIJK (position, color, normal)

In *OpenGL*, I could replace the color of rendering object by disabling vertex attribute with color after binding the vertex buffer and then passing the pointer to the buffer with a goal color by '*glVertexAttrib3fv*' directive, but in *Metal* I did not find a similar mechanism.
My today understanding *Metal* say me that I could take out the colors in separate uniform buffers and pass the desired one to shader. This creates more interesting effects than monochrome coloring. Or I can create a render pass with a different shader. But I would like to know if there are other mechanisms to achieve my goal.